# How call resource controller in Laravel 8.0x

Tags: laravel, controller, resources, laravel-8

when laravel update, some changes in this update, so how to call resource controller give mi example

controller called like:

first use the controller like:
use App\Http\controllers\controller name;

and then

Route::get('/URL', controller-name::class);

but this way i can't call resource controller.

Comment: so use `Route::resource` then .... what is the problem?

Comment: Route::resource('/URL', controller-name::class); but not call show error

Comment: what is the problem? can you actually explain what the issue is with context

Comment: how to call resource controller method, give me one demo so i can understand easily.

Comment: welcome to so, you need to be the one doing the searching, so will help you only, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

The route you have defined only works for single-action controllers that implement the  `__invoke()` method.

If you are dealing with resource controllers, you can either use the tuple syntax or `Route::resource()`

Tuple syntax example:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('posts', [PostController::class, 'store']);
```

Route resource example:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

References:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#single-action-controllers
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers